# Exclude local client from VPN Tunnel on Debian

Tags: networking, debian, routing, iptables, openvpn

So I recently set up a Debian server on my network in order to route all my internet traffic through OpenVPN. I used [this](https://gist.github.com/superjamie/ac55b6d2c080582a3e64) guide to set up the iptables (I did not set up the kill switch though.)

Now, my issue is that apparently Netflix has decided that if you use a VPN you're not allowed to stream anything anymore. So what I'd like to do is to make it so my Chromecast, which is my primary streaming client, doesn't use the VPN Tunnel.

### Network layout:

- Router: 192.168.0.1
- Pi-Hole DNS: 192.168.0.3 (I don't think this is relevant but whatever)
- VPN gateway: 192.168.0.4
- Chromecast: 192.168.0.155 (effectively static)

I've managed to effectively give the Chromecast a static IP by making the router always give it the same address.

The VPN gateway is set on the clients via DHCP and since the Chromecast doesn't allow me to set the gateway manually (which would have solved all my problems) I have to fix this some other way.

So what I want to do is to route all Chromecast traffic via my non-encrypted connection, is there a relatively straightforward way to do so?

I've looked online for a solution, but all I've found are fixes for Pfsense, DD-WRT, Merlin, etc. and I don't know how to adapt them to work with my Debian server.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I solved it using Policy Based Routing.

For anyone who is trying to do something similar, I just needed to set up a new table in `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`,

add a route pointing traffic to my router:

`ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 table custom_table`,

and then add a rule applying said route to any traffic coming from the Chromecast.

`ip rule add from 192.168.0.155 lookup custom_table`

**EDIT:**
Ok, so while this works, it seems to dramatically slow down the network speed of the Chromecast. Guess I'll have to concede to watch Netflix on my Smart TV which does allow me to set the gateway manually.